# Securing RSA key files on Ubuntu server - what permissions?

Tags: php, permissions, rsa

I would like to prevent a client browser from opening the private RSA key file but allow the server run PHP scrips to access the file for decryption purposes.

The `644` rights allow the browser to open the file and `600` block everyone out.

What would be the correct way to secure this file?

Comment: @Just for once, just for testing try: `chmod 644 priv.key&& chown root:root priv.key`. If that works, then we can proceed with other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory permissions should be `700`, the file permissions on all the files should be `600`, and the directory and files should be owned by root.

Or just place it outside of the public directory. And then, set it to `644`.

Comment: @danny26b why do you want the PHP script to gain access?

Comment: @danny26b are you also using it with Apache?

Comment: @danny26b, maybe just place it outside of the public directory. And, just set it to `644`?

Comment: @chi-c-j-rajeeva-lochana, I am going to rethink the keys and just have them in the php file directly, that'll eliminate any issues. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @danny26b make sure not to allow users to visit it directly, you can do it in the Apache configuration

Comment: don't forget, php can read your key outside the public directory, in my opinion it's a better pratice.

Answer (score 1):

you must include in your permissions the account wich must have a read access to the key, example if it's your apache server you should make a chown www-data:www-data and set chmod 660. root will always have access to this file.

Comment: `-rw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 2459 Feb  5 22:52 private-key.pem`

Updates have been made but I am still getting Permission Denied in the PHP error log. :(